# How to stop org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars via my war file's local context.xml rather than altering Tomcat 8?

Tags: servlets, tomcat8, tag-library-descriptor

I'm trying to prevent the...

```
[localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

...error from showing up for my war file deployment since I have no TLD defined.

There are many questions and answers regarding this issue but they all seem to point to altering Tomcat's global configuration, which I do not want.

How can I, **via my war file's local context.xml file**, inform the scanner that no TLD exists and therefore a scan and subsequent warning is unnecessary?

Answer (score 3):

First add `logging.properties` below:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.level = FINE
```

Second restart tomcat.

Third open `logs/catalina.out` and you can find below:

```
31-Oct-2017 09:20:37.563 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/home/vhr/lib/jcert.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
```

Fourth if you don't scan `jcert.jar`, you edit `conf/catalina.properties`, add `jcert.jar` to `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip`.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: OP specifically asked about non-global changes, this is a global change.